# Stop value going into negative in javascript

Tags: javascript, count, negative-number

I have a function where you can click to like, and you kan also click to dislike. How can I make it NOT possible to go to negative number, so that if you click dislike after 0 it stays 0?

```
function stem(id) {
    var antal_stemmer = document.getElementById(id).className; 
    var nyt_antal_stemmer =+ antal_stemmer + +1; 
    document.getElementById(id).className = nyt_antal_stemmer;
    var indhold = document.getElementsByClassName(id); 
    var indholdA = indhold[0].innerHTML; 
    indhold[0].innerHTML = nyt_antal_stemmer + " stemmer"; 
}
function fjern(id) {
    var antal_stemmer = document.getElementById(id).className;
    var nyt_antal_stemmer =+ antal_stemmer - +1;
    document.getElementById(id).className = nyt_antal_stemmer;
    var indhold = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
    var indholdA = indhold[0].innerHTML;
    indhold[0].innerHTML = nyt_antal_stemmer + " stemmer";
}
```

Comment: whare is the part where you decrement a value?

Comment: @NinaScholz perhaps `var nyt_antal_stemmer =+ antal_stemmer - +1;` but...it looks weird.

Comment: Why do you write `- +1` instead of just `- 1`?

Comment: And why do you write `=+`? At first I mistook that for `+=` and thought you were incrementing `nyt_antal_stemmer`.

Comment: `nyt_antal_stemmer =+ antal_stemmer - +1;` is a really, really confusing way to write `nyt_antal_stemmer = antal_stemmer - 1;`

Comment: @Barmar my guess is that `=+` is because `antal_stemmer` is a string, so it's actually more properly written as `var nyt_antal_stemmer = (+antal_stemmer) - 1`. However, speaking of `antal_stemmer`, it's the value of a *class*. It should probably be a `data-*` attribute instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the maximum of the value or zero. The result is a number greater or equal zero.

```
var nyt_antal_stemmer = Math.max(0, antal_stemmer - 1); // - converts the operands to number
```

Comment: Don't add `nyt_antal_stemmer`. It wasn't `+=` in the original code.

Comment: the code is very misleading, the actual value should be `Math.max(0, antal_stemmer - 1);`